# How to automate calculations of sums with harmonic numbers

Tags: summation

I would like to ask if anyone knows how can we automate calculations of the following sum

```
Sum[HarmonicNumber[n]^2/((n + 1) 2^n), {n, 1, ∞}]
```

The analytic result is known and can be verified numerically

```
NSum[HarmonicNumber[n]^2/((n + 1) 2^n), {n, 1, ∞}]

0.650161

Log[2]^3/3 + Zeta[2] Log[2] - Zeta[3]/2 // N

0.650161
```

I would be most interested to see generalizations to other powers $k$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^k}{(n+1)2^n} $$

It might be tempting to say that this question belongs to other pure math-orient stackexchange site. However, analytic calculations are so cumbersome that some help of a computer algebra system is needed.

Mathematical background:

These sums have applications in the calculations of Feynman integrals. Some starting point could be this integral representation of the harmonic number (Euler):
$$ H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x}\,dx. $$

Comment: Do you have a reference for how the analytic result was computed?

Comment: I have upvoted this question, I find it interesting, nonetheless I'd like to know a bit more what is your motivation and what is its application? I guess it is related to calculations in quantum field theory, isn't it?

Comment: For $k=0$ the result is $2\ln2-1$. For $k=1$ the result is $(\ln2)^2$. Maybe if you find the exact results for a few more values of $k$ you can guess a formula or use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html).

Comment: @Artes Yes, you are right, it has a *direct* connection to Feynman integrals. I have updated the question with an integral representation of $H_n$ that might give some hints how the calculation has to be actually performed. However, I did not do these calculations by hand as they seem to cumbersome to me.

Comment: @Roman This might indeed be a very good case for FindSequenceFunction, or to an integer relation algorithm that to the best of my knowledge is implemented in MA. But one needs to know the form, of course.

Comment: @CarlWoll I tried to find some pedagogical article. The best I know is this one D. Borwein, J. M. Borwein, On some intriguing integral and some series related to ζ(4), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 123 (1995) 1191–1198. Not exactly the same some, but similar method.

Comment: @CarlWoll The integral representation of $H_n$ is the common and the main part of the derivation. I've updated the question.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A103930 g.f. for $k=2$ sum

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903520/generating-function-for-cubes-of-harmonic-numbers g.f. for $k=3$

Comment: @JamesArathoon Thanks for useful links!